# Lambda Layer with SAM CLI

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda-layers

I created a lambda layer with serverless successfully but now I have to do the same with SAM CLI but i can't.

With serverless I only use two files:

- serverless.yml
- awswrangler-layer-0.0.23-py3.7.zip

serverless.yml content below:

```
service: MyService

provider:
  name: aws

layers:
  awswrangler:
    package:
      artifact: awswrangler-layer-0.0.23-py3.7.zip
```

How can I do the same with SAM CLI? Please give an example of the template.yaml

Comment: In https://docs.aws.amazon.com/es_es/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-resource-layerversion.html for ContentUri said: "If a local file path is provided, the template must go through the workflow that includes the sam deploy or sam package command, in order for the content to be transformed properly."
OK, but how?

Answer (score 0):

I have to unzip and this was the solution:

```
  AwswranglerLayer :
    Type: AWS::Serverless::LayerVersion
    Properties:
      LayerName: !Join ['-', [!Ref Project, !Ref Environment, 'AwswranglerLayer']]
      ContentUri: ../layers/awswrangler/
      Description: "ETL and wrangling utility belt to handle data on AWS. Pandas, PySpark"
      CompatibleRuntimes:
        - python3.7
        - python3.8
      RetentionPolicy: Retain
```

Answer (score 0):

AwswranglerLayer:
Type: AWS::Serverless::LayerVersion
Properties:
LayerName: !Sub '${EnvironmentKey}-AwswranglerLayer'
CompatibleRuntimes:
- nodejs12.x
ContentUri: AwswranglerLayerPath/